# Shuffling an linked list Java

Tags: java, random, linked-list, shuffle

I'm having a very hard time using a pseudo code  for the shuffling algorithm and turning it to a working java code. I'm attempting to shuffle a linked list. Overall the method takes the pointer of the head of the linked list and returns a pointer to the head of the same list randomly. I want to use a getLength and getItem method I've created.

```
public static ListElement shuffle(ListElement head){
  head = head.getLength();
  ListElement head2= null;
  while( head == null) {
    int random = (int) Math.random() *  n;
    for(int i=0;i<random;i++){
        head= head.getNext();
    }
  }
  return head;    
}
```

Pseudo code:

```
A list L of length n
A new list R, empty
while L is not empty
   pick a random k 
   such that 0<=k<= (length L)
   remove the kth element of L
      call it e
   prepend e to R
```

Comment: What is ListElement? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: @Sujay: I'm quite sure that it's the LinkedList.

Comment: Yes ListElement is the linked list.

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting a bit but it looks like you've got some mismatched braces.

Comment: Is your code cut and paste? head is treated as an element and a length. 'n' is used but not defined. Your pseudo code looks ok - remember as you remove items from L, L's length changes.

Comment: yeah, i've had the same question about the braces! the pseudocode looks okay to me

Comment: Can you not use `shuffle` in `Collections` ?

Comment: I want to learn how to use the math.random() so that's why I'm using this instead of shuffle in collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rewrite the code a bit so that it follows the pseudo code.

```
ListElement head2 = null;
int length = head.getLength();

while (head != null) {
    int k = (int) Math.random() * length;

    // Assume there is function deleteAt(index) that removes
    // the element at specified index and returns the deleted
    // element
    ListElement e = head.deleteAt(k);
    // Although I can just give the implementation - I'll leave this
    // as exercise.

    // You can have a function that add element to front
    // head2.addFront(e);
    e.setNext(head2);
    head2 = e;

    // Instead of querying the length again
    // decrement the length
    length--;
}
return head;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
head = head.getLength();
```

Looks as if it should be `int n = head.getLength();`

```
while( head == null) {
```

Looks as if it should be `while (head != null) {`

```
int random = (int) Math.random() *  n;
for(int i=0;i<random;i++){
    head= head.getNext();
```

You're overwriting the head variable. You need to use a new variable to find the kth element of the list, and leave head pointing to the old list.

You don't do anything yet with the element once you've found it, you need to extract it from the old list (hard) and prepend it to the new list.

```
return head;
```

You need to return the new list.

Comment: There's another problem -- the RNG is liable to generate the same value multiple times so you need to filter that out.

Comment: @user268396 That's not a true shuffle. You need to remove the elements from the list as you go so that you only randomly choose from the remaining elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your pseudocode is that the worst case scenario, you will have to iterate to the end of the original list every time you wanted to remove an element to add it to the new list.

Original list o = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
New list: n = []

o = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
n = [g]

o = [a,b,c,d,e]
n = [g,f]

o = [a,b,c,d]
n = [g,f,e]

...

The best performing answer I can think of now is to create an array the size of the list and iterate through the original linked list, inserting elements to the array at random locations:

Original list o = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
New array a = [,,,,,,]

o = [b,c,d,e,f,g]
a = [,,a,,,,]

o = [c,d,e,f,g]
a = [,,a,,b,,]

o = [d,e,f,g]
a = [c,,a,,b,,]

o = [e,f,g]
a = [c,,a,,b,d,]

...

After you have them in the array, loop through the array and fix the links.

In the original, you'd have to call `getNext()` 6 times, then 5 times, then 4 times, then 3 times...

In mine, you call `getNext()` 6 times, then loop through the array resetting your 'next' references.

Comment: The random number generator is liable to return the same index value multiple times, especially for small lists. This means that in your case you trade the cost of iterating for the cost of generating more random numbers than strictly required... (Plus you'd need to filter such values out as well.)

Comment: If the spot is taken, just take the closest open spot.  Collisions happen