# Shuffling list randomly Java

Tags: java, random, linked-list, shuffle

I'm attempting to randomly shuffle a list. Each time I attempt to test the code it essentially does nothing and doesn't end. I was wondering what exactly am I missing or doing wrong.

```
public static ListElement shuffle(ListElement head){
    int n= ListUtils.getLength(head);
    ListElement head2= null;
    while( head != null) {  
        int random = (int) Math.random() *  n;
        for(int i=0;i<random;i++){
            ListElement list= new ListElement(); 
            list=getItem(head2,n);
            list.getNext();
            head2=list;

        }
    }
    return head2;       
}
```

GetItem

```
public static ListElement getItem(ListElement head, int n){
    if(n == 0){                 
        return head;            
    }else if(head == null){     
        return null;
    }else{                      
        return getItem(head.getNext(),n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `java.util.Collections.shuffle(myList)`

Comment: Where is the code for `getItem()`?

Comment: I need to use Math.random() since I wanna learn how to use it.

Comment: Probably will cause infinite loop with that condition `head != null` and `list` always `null` because you're never update the `head2` variable that will send to `getItem()`.

Comment: If you want better entropy and more unique randoms, consider using SecureRandom.

Comment: I've seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11443233/1065197) yesterday, you came up with a good algorithm to shuffle, but you're not following your algorithm. If you could show how `ListElement` class is constructed will help a lot to the community to answer this question (After what I've read from you, ListElement must be the list, but it looks like the head or first node, so please show us what have you done in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Typo!
You are never updating `head`, which you use in your loop condition.

Comment: Neither do I. I don't think your algorithm makes too much sense. But the reason why the loop doesn't end is because `head` will never be `null` because you never update it to anything. It will always be whatever you pass as an argument to `shuffle`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what getItem method does in the for loop.

An alternative solution if you want to use Math.random() is to go through the whole list, and generate a random index for each element which it will swap with in the list.

```
public void randomize(List<String> myList){
  int n= myList.size();
  for(int i; i < n; i++){
    int randIdx = (int) Math.random() *  n;
    swap(myList, i, randIdx);
  }
}

private void swap(List<String> list, int idx1, int idx2){
  if(idx1 != idx2){ //don't do swap if the indexes to swap between are the same - skip it.
    String tmp = list.get(idx1);
    list.set(idx1, list.get(idx2));
    list.set(idx2, tmp);
  }
}
```